# In Ubuntu 18.04 using Thinkpad, how Settings application is launched when Fn + F9 is pressed?

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad

In ThinkPad X1 Yoga, when I press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> key combination, the Settings application is launched.
Is this a GNOME application?

If yes, is it possible to launch some other application instead of the Settings application when <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> is pressed and how can we achieve it?

Comment: Thank you .. Got below output : **request mappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248**

Comment: Checking it  but as of now unable to find

Comment: keycode is **75**  and got this **XF86Switch_VT_9** ... But i was checking when Fn + F9 key is pressed not F9 is pressed without Fn key .. Thanks

Comment: Ok got it.. `keycode 191 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools` what do you want to achieve in place of this? which application you want to open?

Comment: I want to launch "Keyboard Settings" page of Settings tools or any app like "Calculator"  etc .. May i ask , how you get keycode 191 ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, 191 is a Variable.. it differs from system to system or keyboard to keyboard.. you can Ignore it.. only thing you have to grab from it is the keycode value..

Comment: you can get keyboard settings page of settings with the command `gnome-control-center keyboard` since its a command you need to bind it or try to give this command in custom keyboard shortcuts by pressing Fn+F9.. let me check.. whether keyboard shortcuts is accepting the key press of Fn+F9

Comment: Sorry to ask again but I am unable to launch Keyboard with the command **gnome-control-center keyboard** ... not sure but some device page get popped up every time....

Comment: can you post the screenshot when you run above command in terminal plz

Comment: [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEcaV.pnggg   Settings is not launching using gnome-control-center

Comment: ok what if gnome-control-center only in terminal?

Comment: same screen is shown

Comment: hum.. seems to be different problem...

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center` try this

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the symbol on keyboard there is settings icon on it.. which is may be resulting in opening the system settings..

you can get the keycode of this particular behaving with below command

```
xmodmap -pke | grep XF86Tools
```

Once you got the result with keycode.. you can assign your functions to it with `xmodmap`

for example if the keycode is 191

make the keycode to do nothing when pressed with below command

xmodmap -e "keycode 191 = "

then with `xbindkeys` tool you can bind the command `gnome-control-center keyboard` for this key press Fn+F9 like below

```
"gnome-control-center keyboard"
m:0x0 + c:179
```

Comment: Thank you .. Its helpful

Comment: I have tested it in my Ubuntu 18.04.. Hope you know abuot xbindkeys package installation and xmodmap persistence.. Otherwise I will edit the Answer